# Get GMSPlace from longitude/latitude coordinates?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I looked at the API [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-details), but it only mentions that you can get the GMSPlace for the user's current location. Is there any way to create my own custom GMSPlace object or get the GMSPlace for the lat/long I want? I looked at previous solutions but didn't find anything.

Comment: Why you want to create your own custom GMSPlace object?

Comment: I want to get a GMSPlace object at a different lat/long than my current location

Answer (score 1):

As per Google's docs:

> Represents a particular physical place. A GMSPlace encapsulates
>   information about a physical location, including its name,
>   location, and any other information we might have about it. This 
>   class is immutable.

Apparently there is no way to make your own `GMSPlace` object from the coordinates, nor there' a method that Google's SDK provide.

What I did before, I search for places, the one that Ajay user above discussed.

So the process is:

1. Get coordinates.
2. Reversegeocode to get the string address.
3. Search the string address using the `GooglePlaces` autocomplete.
4. From the first result in #3, the placeId is used to get the `GMSPlace` object using the `lookUpPlaceID` method.

Beware though that sometimes it returns a wrong address. I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

`GMSPlace` is a class provided by `Places SDK` which provides information about a specific place. You can not create your own custom object.

**EDIT**: To find a place other than your current location it provides [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete) api which automatically return location suggestions while users type.

Comment: So how would I get a GMSPlace at a location other than my current location?